# Javascript: set element.style = element.style breaks the styling?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to just store the current style state of an element, so i can botch up the styling then jsut reset it?

Something similar to (although this doesnt work): http://jsfiddle.net/843Pj/

```
var el=document.getElementById('test');

var st=(function(s){
    var r=function(){return s;};
    return r;
}(el.style));

el.style.backgroundColor='blue';

el.style=st();

alert(el.style);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you're trying to set the element's style to a function?

Comment: You're not setting `element.style` to the style object, but rather to a function... What do you expect?

Comment: oops you are right, i rewrote this thing twelves times ill fix it real quick

Comment: fixed it. but even if you use el.style=el.style the styling still breaks.

Comment: `style` is object, so when you pass it to function - you save reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking just about the original inline styles, the use the `.cssText` property of the `style` object.

```
var st = el.style.cssText; // store it

el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; // change it

el.style.cssText = st; // reset it
```

http://jsfiddle.net/843Pj/4/

You could even store it on a `data-` attribute of the element for easy access later.